# Is there an exising portal for uploading to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, cloud, apache-pig, hdfs

I need to set up a web portal for uploading files and tasks to an Hadoop server.
Is there some kind of existing project I can use or start from?

Regards

***Update:***

> Sorry to be a bit vague, but this assignment is a bit vague to me. I
>   have figured out that Hue seems to fit my needs to run pig scripts and
>   upload files to a web service.
>
> The next challenge will be to figure out how the SDK works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Hue you have a file uploader for HDFS. It's a project which joined Cloudera. But the upload part is just a little part of the project. So maybe it's too big for your needs.

http://gethue.com/